# RollupError: "ENV_VAR_NAME" is not exported by "$env/static/private", imported by "src/hooks.server.js". - SvelteKit

Tags: import, svelte, vercel, sveltekit

I am creating a SvelteKit project, and have declared environment variables that I need to access.

**.env**

```
ENV_VAR_NAME='random123'
```

**src/hooks.server.js**

```
import { ENV_VAR_NAME } from '$env/static/private';
//rest of my code here
```

The above code works in development. However, when I deploy it to Vercel, I get the following error. The issue occurs even when I have declared the environment variable in Vercel.

```
RollupError: "ENV_VAR_NAME" is not exported by "$env/static/private", imported by "src/hooks.server.js".
```

Comment: Try changing the way you import the variable:

// src/hooks.server.js

// Access environment variable using import.meta.env
const ENV_VAR_NAME = import.meta.env.VITE_ENV_VAR_NAME;
// rest of your code here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the variable is set dynamically in Vercel and thus not injected into the code at build time, you have to use [`$env/dynamic/private`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-dynamic-private) instead.

> This module provides access to runtime environment variables, as defined by the platform you're running on.

Comment: I have a similar error and my variable is not set dynamically, at least that is not the intention. Is there anything else I could be missing? Thanks!

Comment: @thib: There was [an issue with environment variables](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/11425) in v2, but that should have be patched. Other than that I do not know.

Comment: Thank you @brunnerh I used `svelte-kit sync` as suggested in this comment and it worked: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/11425#issuecomment-1892349204